# how to implement own code on services created by feathersJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, feathersjs

I want to use feathersJS  for a project. I have gone through the documentation and also tried to go through the chat app available on documentation but still, I have not got it well.

As I understood for each functionality they create service and database, for example for user and message, there are two services have created which use Nedb database.

My question is, should I create services which contain a database for every functionality am going to implement? second, for every service created by feathers there app.js, so the logic code I want writes other than what created by feathersJS needs be written on app.js or need to create another app.js by myself?

I would also appreciate if you could suggest me some projects done by using feathersJS.

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and clear problem statement. What did you try? *should I create services which contain a database for every functionality am going to implement* - I'm not sure what does this means. Please, show your current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the CLI to create the application and services? Maybe will be easier. But actually is not necessary to create a database for every service, except if is really necessary to use more than 1.

About the logic codes, it depends. It can be handled as a [express middleware](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html) or in the [service hooks (for every service or for the application)](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html). This second case is more about pre and post processing the client request. Of course, the operation made itself can be a class, a function or even an API call. For example, you can check a param sent by client in the request only before to execute the 'get' operation adding the ckeck into GET before hook. Also have a hook to check the authentication.

```
//in other some place
module.exports = (hook) => {
    return hook.params.query.device_type === 'smartphone' 
    ? console.log('is a smartphone request')
    : console.log('is not a smartphone request');
}

//src/services/devices/devices.hooks.js
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;
const myVerification = require('path/to/myverification');
const myVerification2 = require('path/to/myverification2');

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    find: [],
    get: [myVerification, myVerification2],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you Luiz, for your answer. I have different tables which linked to each other through foreign key so I want implement those tables by using NeDb.  I am just trying to use only the featherjs without using express or others I mean by using only what feathers provide . For clarity does it require to use for example express for client and as backend featherjs or I can only build the Application Only by using featherjs. In chat app from documentation they only used featherjs. I would appreciate if you give me some clarity.

Comment: Feathers is a fw express-based. In other words, everything that works in express, should work in feathers. But the point is when you create a service, by the Feathers CLI, it usually asks you about the database you are using or want to use. Kind it has a good abstraction. But this problem does affect the database choice itself. If you have a relational structure and need to use NeDB, then you will need to change the data approach (not using table strcuture). Otherwise, you can use some adapter for relational db by feathers, like Sequelize or Knex instead NeDB.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation